Functions inside inherited Cheetah template can't see global variables
I have some Cheetah templates that are structured using inheritance.
basepage.tmpl:
from quixote.publish import get_session()

#set global $session = get_session()

#block content
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="$session.lang">
  <head>
    ... meta tags, stylesheets, etc ...
  </head>
  #block body
  <body></body>
  #end block body
</html>
#end block

anactualpage.tmpl:
#extends basepage

#def some_content
  ... content ...
  $session.some_variable
  ... content ...
#end def

#def body
<body>
  ... body ...
  $some_content
  ... more body ...
</body>
#end def

Quixote is my web framework, but it could be any Python library. Importing isn't even the problem here; it's just that I setup a few global variables using some functions imported from various libraries so this illustrates my use case.
When I invoke the template anactualpage in my code it generates the entire page of output as desired without any problems.
If instead I want to return just part of the template, anactualpage.some_content() — for example in response to an AJAX request where I want to return just a part of the entire page — I get NameMapper.NotFound in the compiled template code where the variable lookup function VFFSL is looking for session.some_variable in the search list SL (VFFSL and SL are used by Cheetah into the compiled code).
I can work around the error by adding extra imports and sets inside the child template — specifically inside the some_content function — but why is this necessary?
Is this a bug in Cheetah? I presume not and that I'm abusing it somehow.
Is there any other way to make (global) variables always available in the search list so they can be referenced by functions called separately from the entire template?

This is not a bug, this is how Cheetah works. Run
cheetah compile basepage.tmpl

and see inside basepage.py. The global variable session is initialized this way:
    def respond(self, trans=None):
…
        self._CHEETAH__globalSetVars["session"] = …

inside method respond. When you call the entire template anactualpage.tmpl the method is called and the variable is initialized. When you call anactualpage.some_content() directly method respond is not called and the variable is not initialized. You need to find a way to reinitialize it in actualpage.tmpl.

What is the best way to achieve what I want? Create more layers of inheritance so that the individual function is an entire template by itself at a higher level? This could get unwieldy. I'm thinking of using a function to initialise my searchlists with some standard variables.

@Colin'tHart Declare session as a class attribute: #attr $session = get_session() . Then it will be available in the class and all its descendants.
